# In Rails, how do I return an associated record using includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm aware of the includes, and extract_associated methods.

extract_associated as used here, in the Rails docs, only returns the user records -

```
account.memberships.extract_associated(:user)
# => Returns collection of User records
```

I'm looking to return the Membership records, WITH the User records in the same array.  I know that the `includes` method should do this for me, but my response only includes the user_id and not the actual record, i.e. the use of includes hasn't changed what's returned at all, like so:-

```
account.memberships.includes(:user)
# => Returns collection of Membership records, with user_ids 
[{ "id": 3, "account_id": 1, "user_id": 2, "membership_name": 'Annual Membership'}]
```

My Memberships belongs_to a User, and a User has_many Memberships.

What am I missing here?

It's not an option for me to do `membership.user` in my view, because I'm using VueJS so need to pass all the data I need in.

Comment: Working with the objects is the best/ruby way of doing it. That said, try to use both "joins" and "includes" and see if that gets you what you need. Hopefully you can get what you need from that as is, but otherwise you'll need to specify a "select" as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can include association's collection as json.

```
account.memberships.includes(:user)
       .as_json(include: { memberships: { include: :user } })
```

See the details for API from documentation.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html